# how to call dynamic form name in the django template

Tags: python, django-templates

i have two forms called

```
`{{form.f1}}`
```

and

```
`{{form.f2}}`.
```

i would like to acces the two forms(f1 and f2) in the django template via forloop. my forloop is

```
{% for n in formList %}
{{form.f?}}
{% endfor %}
```

in my view.py, formList is

```
{'formList':range(1,3)}
```

i do not know how to integrate N in the forloop and i need your help to call the dynamic forms.

thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make your `formList` a list of those forms, not their indices. Then you could simply iterate over the list and not try to access them using indices.

So:

```py
{'formList': [form.f1, form.f2]}
```

And then in the template:

```html
{% for f in formList %}
    {{ f }}
{% endfor %}
```